# Custom components in JSF - what about sub-components (children)

Tags: jsf, components

When Im creating custom *component* in JSF do I have to create all *sub-components* in that same way?

---

*For example:*

h:dataTable component use h:column to determinate column parameters

---

Now if I want to create **dataTable** component do I have to implement in that same way a **column** component?

(PS. "that same way" mean:

- create DataTable class extends i.e. UIOutput
- create DataTableTab class extends UIComponentELTag
- append configuration to
  custom.taglib.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the answer is no. If you create a complex component like a datatable, it can simply take advantage of the existing components for defining columns.

As the designer of such a dataTable, you are the one who determines what's needed. The standard column afaik has no knowledge of the dataTable, but the dataTable has knowledge about the columns.

Also note that you don't often need to create tag classes. This is only needed for JSP compatibility, but as JSP is deprecated I would advise you to not support it unless you really have to.